# jq: map object if field exists

Tags: jq

This is my jq code:

```
def pick_nationality:
  {nation: {country: .NACIONALITAT, code: "some code"} };

def pick_surname:
  {name: {surname: .SURNAME, code: "some code"} };

map([pick_nationality, pick_surname])
```

Problem here appears when some of `.NACIONALITAT` or `.SURNAME` is not present on input objects:

```json
{
  "SURNAME": "surname1"
}
{
  "NACIONALITAT": "nacionalitat1"
}
```

Result:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "nation": {
        "country": null,
        "code": "some code"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "surname": "surname1",
        "code": "some code"
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "nation": {
        "country": "nacionalitat1",
        "code": "some code"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "surname": null,
        "code": "some code"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Problem is I need to avoid pick_natinality when `.NATIONALITAT` field is not present...

Desired result would be:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "name": {
        "surname": "surname1",
        "code": "some code"
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "nation": {
        "country": "nacionalitat1",
        "code": "some code"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have the functions return nothing when the relevant field is missing.

```
def pick_nationality:
  select(.NACIONALITAT) |
  {nation: {country: .NACIONALITAT, code: "some code"} };

def pick_surname: 
  select(.SURNAME) |
  {name: {surname: .SURNAME, code: "some code"} };

map([pick_nationality, pick_surname])
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/v5k_Qjeoc3) on jqplay

Answer (score 1):

You can use **del** for the respective ***null*** values such as

```
jq -r 'del(.[][] | select(.nation.country == null and .name.surname== null))'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/d_Ii1AmCI1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can add a test before capture the value :

```
def pick_nationality:
  if has("NACIONALITAT")
  then {nation: {country: .NACIONALITAT, code: "some code"} }
  else empty end;

def pick_surname: 
  if has("SURNAME")
  then {name: {surname: .SURNAME, code: "some code"} }
  else empty end;

map([pick_nationality, pick_surname])
```